# WebAPI with Sharepoint Content Search

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sharepoint, office365api

I have a website made in php, and on the other hand i Have content on SharePoint/Office 365. Now i want to build a ASP.NET WebAPI who can call that SharePoint Content search and Returns a RestFul or JSON result containing name of the files.

I am a beginner in SharePoint however intermediate in ASP.NET MVC/ WebAPI. Any Help will be Appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to host web api - 
i. Internal - Inside sharepoint environment
ii. External - On some IIS server

For the first option, I don't know if you really need your web api since sharepoints, by default, provides an api to deal with sharepoint content.

Considering your web api is hosted in IIS on some server, you need to add two dlls in your solution.
1. Sharepoint.client
2. Sharepoint.client.runtime

Then using 'ClientContext' class and its properties/methods & CAML queries, you can access the sharepoint list and it's contents. (This is not my area of expertise but I've once worked on such scenario). Anyway I do have a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code) that you can refer to get some heads up.

Hope this helps!